# Making Java version of Notepad and I have a problem

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, swingworker

I am trying to load all types of files (like Microsoft Notepad). The SwingWorker I have can load normal text just fine but when a file such as mp3, pdf, etc. is attempted to be loaded I receive a NullPointerException.

Can someone take a look at my code and possibly see why I keep getting this error for files such as mp3, pdf, etc.? Like I said I can load normal .html plain text files w/o any errors.

```
class Open extends SwingWorker<StringBuilder, Void>
{
    File file;
    JTextArea jta;

    Open(File file, JTextArea jta)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.jta = jta;
    }

    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while(br.ready())
            {
                b.append(br.readLine() + "\n");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
        try {
            jta.append(get().toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get after turning the code into:

```
class Open extends SwingWorker<Void, String>
{
    File file;
    JTextArea jta;

    Open(File file, JTextArea jta)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.jta = jta;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line != null)
            {
                publish(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks)
    {
        for(String s : chunks)
            jta.append(s + "\n");
    }
}
```

This is the 'stacktrace' (I think) from Netbeans:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
        at sun.font.PhysicalStrike.getGlyphPoint(PhysicalStrike.java:112)
        at sun.font.SunLayoutEngine.nativeLayout(Native Method)
        at sun.font.SunLayoutEngine.layout(SunLayoutEngine.java:133)
        at sun.font.GlyphLayout$EngineRecord.layout(GlyphLayout.java:648)
        at sun.font.GlyphLayout.layout(GlyphLayout.java:447)
        at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createGV(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:308)
        at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getGV(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:294)
        at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:563)
        at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:492)
        at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getLineBreakIndex(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:438)
        at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.calcLineBreak(TextMeasurer.java:308)
        at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.getLineBreakIndex(TextMeasurer.java:544)
        at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(LineBreakMeasurer.java:340)
        at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:422)
        at javax.swing.text.TextLayoutStrategy.sync(TextLayoutStrategy.java:298)
        at javax.swing.text.TextLayoutStrategy.insertUpdate(TextLayoutStrategy.java:52)
        at javax.swing.text.FlowView.loadChildren(FlowView.java:126)
        at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.setParent(CompositeView.java:122)
        at javax.swing.text.FlowView.setParent(FlowView.java:272)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI$PlainParagraph.setParent(BasicTextAreaUI.java:222)
        at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.replace(CompositeView.java:200)
        at javax.swing.text.BoxView.replace(BoxView.java:164)
        at javax.swing.text.View.updateChildren(View.java:1095)
        at javax.swing.text.View.insertUpdate(View.java:679)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1590)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1849)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:185)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:734)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:693)
        at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:114)
        at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(JTextArea.java:470)
        at Open.process(main.java:313)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$3.run(SwingWorker.java:391)
        at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:95)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:860)
        at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:95)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:870)
        at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
        at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I have changed the code to:

```
class Open extends SwingWorker<Void, String>
{
    File file;
    JTextArea jta;

    Open(File file, JTextArea jta)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.jta = jta;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line != null)
            {
                publish(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks)
    {
        for(String s : chunks)
            jta.append(s + "\n");
    }
}
```

And I still receive NPE.

Comment: I cant get anything from it... Where should I put the stacktrace?

Comment: Use a catch on that try/finally block where you're setting up the reader.

Comment: Alright edited with additional info

Comment: I have changed the BufferedReader to:

br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))); 

and the NPE still is still persistent

Comment: Well I do not want to deal with loading 'binary' streams and displaying it. Is there a way to detect if the stream is 'binary' and cancel loading it?

Answer (score 1):

If the file open fails, the `br` will still be `null` in the finally block where you call `br.close()`.  Hence you'll get an NPE.

I should add that attempting to read a png, pdf or whatever file using FileReader is pointless.  Even if you succeed in opening the file, reading using a Reader is likely to mangle the (binary) contents when it converts from bytes to characters.  The BufferedReader.readLine() call is only going to make things worse ...

EDIT - the supplied stacktrace says clearly that your problem is not related to the code you posted.  But my point still stands.  The code that you posted *will* throw an NPE in the circumstances I described.

The stacktrace seems to be saying that a 'PlainDocument' cannot render random crap masquerading as text.  It looks like it is trying to create glyph information for a (probably garbage) character, and failing because some data structure has not been created / supplied.  I think you'll need to start looking at the Sun source code to figure this out.  A decent IDE will probably help as well.

EDIT 2 - AFAIK, there are two ways you could deal with binary files in the context of a Swing JTextArea.

1. You could read the file as bytes (using a Stream), translate the bytes into something displayable (e.g. replacing undisplayable characters with sequences of displayable characters), and then use a read-only PlainDocument to display them.
2. If you want something that allows you to edit binary files (and I'm not sure that's a sensible idea), I think you'll need to create your own Document type.  That could be a big task.

Comment: I would have loved for that to work testing if br != null did not fix the problem.

Comment: What do you recommend that I do? I want to achieve the same thing that Notepad does.

Answer (score 1):

Java documentation indicates that you shouldn't use [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) for non-text files, use FileInputStream instead.

Might try that route with your original code...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the function Open.process()

Here's the key part of the stacktrace:

```
at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(JTextArea.java:470)
at Open.process(main.java:313)
```

Most likely the problem is that you're appending a null string. Make sure the text you insert is non-null.

try this:

```
    for(String s : chunks)
        if(s != null)
            jta.append(s + "\n");
```

The other thing, make sure you never ignore these exceptions: You never want to have code like

try{
  ...
}
catch(Exception e){ }

Unless you **know** for sure the exceptions won't matter (like an interrupted exception while you're waiting on something in a thread).  You should call e.printStackTrace(); at least so that you can at least **see** that an unanticipated problem came up.

In the code you posted, ignored two errors, first on the reading, then on the close.

Comment: if(s !=  null) did not work as well. Do you think that it is possible that the string is filling up and that is causing the NPE?

Comment: See my other answer.  I think you are having trouble because you are trying to draw characters that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for creating br

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
```

If that works also try

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

And see if that works (you'll need to import java.nio.charset.Charset)